# MPC-HC live thumbnail on Windows taskbar

Tags: windows, media-player-classic

I have a problem with Media Player Classic thumbnail in Windows taskbar. In fact, the thumbnail shows a fix screenshot of the moment when I minimise.
So is there any way to make it show the live video just like Windows Media Player?
Thanks.

Comment: Still no answers?

Comment: The behavior you describe, is a feature of Windows Media Player, and thus would have to be added to Media Player Classic.

Comment: Ah, so nothing can be done...

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnail becomes fixed because MPC is no longer rendering output, there's no point as it feels you can't see it anyway. However there is hope, this is a codec/DirectShow issue. If you enter `Options/Playback/Output` and under `DirectShow Video` select `Enchanced Video Renderer`, DirectShow will render it in the windows taskbar thumbnail preview. (Close MPC or open a new file for the codec to change).

[image: MPC options selecting Enchanced Video Renderer]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't work for me.